# Combinations and Permutations: Number of ways of taking out 1 $ bills

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Can A has N 1 $ bills. Can B is empty. At each step you can either take a bill from can A or put a bill you already have into can B. You can choose to keep some bills in your hand and take some more bills from can A. At the end all the bills should be in can B.

For e.g. Let N = 10, I can do a sequence:

take 1, take 1, take 1, put 1, put 1, take 1 take 1, put 1, take 1, put 1, put 1, take 1, take 1, put 1, take 1, take 1, put 1, put 1, put 1, put 1

In how many possible ways can I do this?

I am trying to reduce this to a problem of solving number of non-negative solutions of equations 
     x1 - y1 >=0;
     x1 + x2 - (y1 + y2) >= 0;
     x1 + x2 + x3 - (y1 + y2 + y3) >= 0

where xis correspond to taking a xi bills from can A and yi to putting yi bills in can B.
But, I am stuck here and not able to go any further.

Consider the case when all the bills are distinct. Now, how many permutations are there in which I can do the above process?

Comment: This is the [catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: Thanks that solves the problem. What if all the bills are distinct and I am I interested in the number of possible such permutations instead of combinations?

Comment: I think the question is incomplete without stating that at the end of the game all the \$1 bills must be in can B. Otherwise, for example, I can take all \$1 bills and stop playing.

Comment: Thanks. Made the edit now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can associate each dollar bill with a letter, and then consider a word of length $2n$ (where $n$ is the number of dollar bills) with the requirement that each associated letter appears exactly twice in the word.  Each such word will give us a unique (up to permutation) way to draw the dollar bills and put them into can B by moving along the word from left to right, and when we encounter a letter the first time we move the associated dollar bill from can A to our hand, and when we encounter it the second time we move it from our hand to can B.

For example, for three dollar bills we could associate the letters a,b,c, and the word 'abbcca' would tell us how to move the dollar bills; first moving a to our hand, then b, then moving b to can B, and so forth.

It then suffices to count the number of such words which are distinct, which is $\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^n}$.

Answer (score -1):

It's a simple 2D path problem with a square grid. With N rights and N downs to go, the number is
$${2N \choose N}$$

Comment: yeah pretty much if they the bills are unique just dong permutations

Comment: The important difference is that you cannot put more bills in can B than you took from can A. So, it cannot be 2D problem, where you can take right or down independent of the other.